# Postgresql query in curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, postgresql-9.1

I have a Postgresql 9.1 table that includes columns "city", "admin1", and "country". I would like to select unique values with the output format of "city, admin1, country".

I may have multiple entries for New York and Rochester, Minnesota, but I only want one of each. This is to populate an elastic search index and I am using the [JDBC river plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)

The following SELECT does what I want in PGAdmin3's SQL editor:

```
SELECT city || ', ' || admin1 || ', ' || country AS city FROM table GROUP BY city, admin1, country;
```

but fails in the following

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/nibbel_river/_meta' -d '{

           "type" : "jdbc",
           "jdbc" : {
               "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
               "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/table",
               "user" : "",
               "password" : "",
           "sql" : "SELECT city || ', ' || admin1 || ', ' || country AS city FROM everything GROUP BY city, admin1, country",
           "poll" : "7d"
           },
           "index" : {
               "index" : "city",
               "type" : "everything"
           }
       }'
```

with the error

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host ' || admin1 || ,'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 102
{"error":"MapperParsingException[Failed to parse [jdbc.sql]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: [B@1192b0c; line: 8, column: 565]]; ","status":400}
```

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All apostrophes in your query have to be escaped like this: `'\''` For example:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/nibbel_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/table",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "SELECT city || '\'', '\'' || admin1 || '\'', '\'' || country AS city FROM everything GROUP BY city, admin1, country",
        "poll" : "7d"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "city",
        "type" : "everything"
    }
}'
```